# Append a row to the bottom of a table with button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an excel sheet that I can distribute between my colleagues which will be used to log the completion of various tasks for work.

Whereby I have a row with 5 fields:

```
| Ref No. | Category | Task Name | Task Notes | Timestamp | 
|   5     |  Sales   | Create Ad | blah blah  | now       |
```

The idea is that someone fill those details in, writing down some more details regarding what task they completed, then they press the button and that row is wiped clean (preferably), and the values are copied to a list of these rows just a couple cells lower.

```
| Ref No. | Category | Task Name | Task Notes | Timestamp | 
|   #     |  Select  |   Blank   | - Blank -  |           |

              | <Button> |


| Ref No. | Category | Task Name | Task Notes | Timestamp | 
|   2     |  Sales   | xxxxxxxxx | blah blah  | xxx       |
|   3     |  Sales   | xxxxxxxxx | blah blah  | xxx       |
|   4     |  Sales   | xxxxxxxxx | blah blah  | xxx       |
|   5     |  Sales   | Create Ad | blah blah  | now       |
```

I have only started getting into VBA due to an obvious need to learn for work, but I've been experimenting with this code which I found somewhere on here a while ago, but can't seem to find the source.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sub copydata()
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Sheets("Activity").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheets("Activity")
        .Range("B3:F3").Copy
        .Range("B" & lrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

When I run the code, close VBA editor, and press the button I get the error:

> Compile error:
>      Expected End Sub

I've tried to troubleshoot, but all of the "fixes" point to there being nothing wrong.

Any help is appreciated. I've enrolled in a udemy course for VBA, but would like to figure this out as soon as possible for work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you tried to put a sub into a sub

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sub copydata()
```

So either end the first sub `CommandButton1_Click` befor starting a new one

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'some code
End Sub

Sub copydata()
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Sheets("Activity").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheets("Activity")
        .Range("B3:F3").Copy
        .Range("B" & lrow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Or kick one of the `Sub` lines off.

Comment: He mentioned a button, so I think getting rid of the line `Sub copydata()` will solve the problem.